# Json object display

Tags: jquery, json

I am getting a json result like this after making an ajax call

```
{"answer":{"isPresent":true,"test":{"string":[""]},"Id":310}}
```

i want the contents of test in an text area. When i retrieve and display the contents of "test" in a text area  i am getting only this

```
[Object object]
```

how to serialize this value?

Code:

```
$.ajax(
        {
                async:      true,
                beforeSend: function(){

                            },
                url:        'beginDisplay.do',
                type:       'POST',
                data:       param,
                dataType:   'json',
                success:    function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){ 

                                var isPresent= data.answer.isPresent;
                                if(isPresent){

                                var testString = data.answer.test;
                                $("#textArea").val(testString);


                            },
                error  :    function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                                //alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText+" http code"+XMLHttpRequest.statusCode);
                                //alert('XMLHttpRequest:'+XMLHttpRequest+'===>> textStatus:'+textStatus+'==>>errorThrown:'+errorThrown);
                            },
                complete :  function(){
                                //alert('after complete....');
                                //unblockUI();
                            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: Can you paste the code you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I test in javascript console:

```
var j = {"answer":{"isPresent":true,"test":{"string":["text you want"]},"Id":310}};
console.log(j.answer.test.string)
>> ["text you want"]
```

In the result above, j.answer.test.string is still an object, therefore you need to specify the node value you want.

So, in your code, you may do this:

```
var testString = data.answer.test.string[0];
$("#textArea").val(testString);
```

However, I suggest you not to use "string" as your variable id. Use something like "str" instead.

Gory details: http://json.org/js.html

Answer (score 1):

you'll want to use the `JSON.stringify` method, provided by the [JSON2 library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js), and natively by most browsers (except IE<=7) if you want a JSON serialized version of the data in the text area.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, the data inside `test` *is* an object. You named the variable `testString`, but really the value of `testString` is the object `{"string":[""]},"Id":310}`

If you want something other than raw json data inside the text box you will need to access the two fields inside `test` and concatenate them into the format you want. If raw json is ok see [@tobyodavies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536481/json-object-display/5536515#5536515) excellent answer. :)